# Change form input attribute

Tags: 7

I have form with an alt attribute like the following.

```
<input type="text" alt="abc">
```

I want to replace that attribute with *data-alt*.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function theme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach($form["submitted"] as $newForm)
    {
        foreach($newForm as $keyid=>$frmArr)
        {
            if(isset($frmArr[]["#attributes"]["alt"]))
            {
                    $alt = $frmArr["#attributes"]["alt"];
                    unset($newForm[$keyid]["#attributes"]["alt"]);
                    $newForm[$keyid]["#attributes"]["data-alt"] = $alt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is not working either.

```
foreach($form["submitted"] as $newForm)
    {

        foreach($newForm as $keyid=>$frmArr)
        {
            if($keyid=='#attributes'){
                $newForm[$keyid]['data-alt']=$newForm[$keyid]['alt'] ;
                 unset($newForm[$keyid]['alt'] );
                $form["submitted"]['#attributes']['alt'] = array("sss");
                form_set_value($form["submitted"]['#attributes']['alt'], array("aaa"), $form_state);
            }
        }


    }
```

What code should I use to achieve what I want?

Comment: isset($frmArr[]["#attributes"]["alt"])
This could never work. Isset is a check on whether something exists and [] is designed to create. Maybe all you need to do is delete those 2 characters.

Comment: i updated code that seems not working

Comment: There's numerous things wrong with the rest of the code also actually. hook_form_alter is used to alter $form and/or $form_state. What you are doing is using them to create new variables, and then not using those to manipulate $form or $form_state.
Besides that you should fix your coding style a bit. Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards that and apply as much as you can.

Comment: theme_form_alter will never be called. It has to be the name of your module or theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
function act_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the_id_of_your_form') {
    unset($form['submitted']['#attributes']['alt']);
    $form['submitted']['#attributes']['data-alt'] = 'abc';
  }
}
```

Won't this work?

Comment: this also not works

Comment: Any idea why? Did you alter the actual id of your form in the code sample and does the code get executed or does nothing happen or what?